# "set /p myvar= < file.txt" does not work - why?

Tags: sqlite, windows-7, batch-file, dos

I have a small Win7 dos batch and I am wondering how to do it right. Here what I do:

```
@echo OFF
@FOR %%D IN (*.sqlite) DO (
    sqlite3 %%D "pragma integrity_check;" > %%D.check
    type %%D.check
    set /p CHECK= < %%D.check
    del %%D.check
    echo "%CHECK%"
)
```

I would expect that CHECK is set to the result of sqlite output. Though "type" shows the expected result, CHECK is empty!

And I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

I also tried it without using a tmpfile

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('sqlite3 %%D "pragma integrity_check;"') do SET CHECK=%%i
```

but this also does not work...

I'd appreciate any help/hint.

Tnx in advance,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Check` is set to the correct value, but you can't see it with `echo %check%`, as this line is expanded while parsing the complete FOR-block, not at the execution time.
You can change to delayed expansion or a simple call :subroutine.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%D IN (*.sqlite) DO (
    sqlite3 %%D "pragma integrity_check;" > %%D.check
    type %%D.check
    set /p CHECK= < %%D.check
    del %%D.check
    echo "!CHECK!"
)
```

or

```
@echo OFF
FOR %%D IN (*.sqlite) DO (
    sqlite3 %%D "pragma integrity_check;" > %%D.check
    type %%D.check
    set /p CHECK= < %%D.check
    del %%D.check
    call :output
)
exit /b

:output
echo "%CHECK%"
exit /b
```

Comment: Perfect! With EnableDelayedExpansion it works fine now.

Tnx very much!

Answer (score 0):

if `%%D.check` contain not only one line

then the `set /p=`will...?